# I cant make my new thread to function

Tags: android, google-maps, http-get

im really new to android and i need my app to send my current coordinates to my webapp , to achieve this i made a new thread, but the thread isn't doing anything. the magic is supost to happen in the SendQueryString() function.
My code is :

```
     @Override
     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
     // Draw the marker, if destination location is not set
     latitude = location.getLatitude();
     longitude = location.getLongitude();
     if (mMarkerPoints.size() < 2) {

     mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
     mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
     LatLng point = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);

     mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
     mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18));

     drawMarker(point);
     }
     String Text = "My current Latitude = " + latitude + " Longitude = "
     + longitude;
     Thread trd = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    SendQueryString();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        trd.start();


     }

    public void SendQueryString() {
                String url = "http://sistemamedicointegrado.azurewebsites.net/Home/Ubicacion?latitud="
                        + latitude + "&longitud=" + longitude + "&id=4";

                try {
                    HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
                    Client.execute(httpget);

                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
            }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }


    }
```

Comment: It's probably doing something, but you have an empty catch block there.  Never do that.  If there's an error, you'll never know what it was.

Comment: What should i put there?

Comment: @guelo `ex.printStackTrace()`

Answer (score 0):

Displaying Toast in a Thread won't work. Ui can be updated only on the ui thread.

You have

```
  SendQueryString();
```

in Threads run method

Then in `SendQueryString()` you display

```
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YESS",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

which is wrong.

Instead of `Thread` you can use `Asynctask` where you can override `onPreExecute`, `onPostExecute` and `onProgressUpdate` and update ui. You can do your background work in `doInBackground`.

Comment: @guelo it should cause all you do is a httpget request. It works. What is that you are looking for. You can log in `SendQueryString()` to check

Comment: is not even entering to that function

Comment: @guelo Log something in your threads run method see if that works. If that does not log anything that means thread is not started. It should according to me.

Comment: is not displaying anything in the log :(

Comment: @guelo are you sure that this `onLocationChanged` is called cause the thread is started in that function. also check if you have any exceptions. If it does not start a thread then `onLocationChanged` is not  called

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51636/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-guelo)

Answer (score 0):

To show toast inside thread means you have to use runonUIThread

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {

```
                 Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this,"YESS",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Otherwise use handler to set message and communicate to the main UI thread.for Example

```
Inside thread use this code 

h.sendEmptyMessage(0);

and then  call this handleMessage method

Handler h = new Handler() {
  public void handleMessage(Message msg){
    if(msg.what == 0){
      Toast.makeText(Activityname, "HelloWorld!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
};
```